# Class aware visual dictionary creation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to use visual dictionary for visual categorization in images.I know how to create dictionary without knowing the class information.For instance the opencv code is as follows.

```
 Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster();//each row is a cluster centroid vector
 bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);
```

Where bowTrainer contains descriptor for each image and bowDE is surf Bag of word descriptor extractor.But here I do not use class information to set dictionary.How can I set half words in a dictionary to as belonging to one class and rest to other? Thanks!
I found the concept used in this paper http://www.decom.ufop.br/sibgrapi2012/eproceedings/technical/ts9/102146_3.pdf see Compute Intermediate-level Features section.

Comment: Train two dictionaries.

Comment: @old-ufo:But after that I want to train SVM for classification how can that be done using descriptors of two dictionaries?

Comment: Sorry, but could you make more clear, what the purpose of using class label in BoW dictionary? BoW is not a classification, it is just used for getting another representation of image.

Comment: The purpose is just for setting half words as belonging to one class and half to other class while training the dictionary.I am using binary classification.Please see the paper at the link in question.

Comment: As far as I understood from the paper, they have applied labels after dictionary created. OpenCV BoW implementation has not such possibility, you have to write you own structure around OpenCVs. Simple vector, containing number if visual word and attribute presence would fit.

Answer (score 0):

As @old-ufo commented, you simply train two dictionaries.  If you want k-dimensional feature vector, you train 2 * k/2 dictionaries, one for each class.  To put into an SVM vector for training your classifier, you build two histograms of k /2 dimensions, one from each dictionary, and then you concatenate them into one feature vector of size k.

So in OpenCV just do the same as you have already done, but do it twice, once for each class, so you have two dictionaries: bowDE1 and bowDE2. Then you calculate the descriptor for each one, and then concatenate them into a single descriptor for svm training.

Cheers